# Number of diagonals of a regular convex $n$-gon.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Consider a regular convex polygon with $n$ sides. I know that the number of lines connecting any two points of the $n$-gon is given by $n \choose 2$, and hence the number of diagonals in the $n$-gon is given by ${n\choose{2}} - n$.

However I wish to find the number of diagonals such that there are $k$ vertices between the two vertices that are connected by the diagonal.

I denote the number of such diagonals by $D_n(k)$.

The maximum number of vertices in between any two diagonals is just $n-3$, but I have noticed if we put $k$ in between $\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor - 1$ and $n-2$, we start to recount the same diagonals that are already counted for some lower $k$. For example when we count for a pentagon, $k=1$ and $k=2$ just give the same diagonals.

To be more precise, I think that $D_n(k) = D_n(n-2-k)$. So I think it makes sense to restrict $k$ such that $0< k < \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor$.

For example:

$$
D_4(1) = 2 \\
D_5(1) = 5 \\ 
D_6(1) = 6 \\
D_6(2) = 3 \\
D_7(1) = 7 \\
D_7(2) = 7
$$ and so on. What I have noticed is that for $n>4$ and $k=1$, $D_n(k) = n$, but I am not sure if that is always the case. Is there some closed form for $D_n(k)$ or just some method to work it out?

Thanks to user @OscarLanzi, I have worked out the for odd $n$, the number of diagonals for all possible $k$ is $n$, whereas for even $n$, it is $n$ for $k \in [1, \frac{n}{2} - 2]$ and $\frac{n}{2}$ for $k=\frac{n}{2} -1$.

Comment: @Invisible, I am not looking for the number of diagonals but rather a count for the number of diagonals that obey a particular constraint. That post does not answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a table with eught columns and five rows. The columns represent $n$ values from $3$ to $10$, the rows represent $k$ values from $0$ to $4$. Fill in the table with the appropriate diagonal counts, leaving areas blank where $k\ge n/2$.

What relationship do you notice between the diagonal counts $n$ and $k$ in most of the table? Can you see why certain numbers along the "edge" of the entries are less than that?

Draw out the polygons for some combinations of $n$ and $k$ to see what is happening geometrically.

Comment: Is it true that for any $n > 4$, the number of diagonals with $k$ from $1$ to $\lfloor n/2\rfloor - 2$ is equal to $n$ and then the number of diagonals with $k=\lfloor n/2 \rfloor - 1$ is just the sum of number of diagonals of all the $k$s subtracted from the total number of diagonals?

Comment: That's what itvlooks like. Might there be a simpler formula when $k=(n/3)-1$ with $n$ even? (What do those diagonals look like geometrically?)

Comment: Did you mean $n/2$ since $n$ is even? Or is it that you want to me check for those with $n$ divisible by $3$?

Comment: I also can't help but notice that for odd $n$, the number of diagonals for each possible $k$ is $n$ as in a pentagon, septagon, nonagon and hendecagon.

Comment: You should not see anything new with $n$ divisible by $3$. Nothing in your table for $n=3,6,9$ would suggest any such thing.

Comment: Is it that for even $n$ the diagonal count for increasing $k$ goes like: $n,n,n,\dots n, (n/2)$ and for odd $n$ it goes like $n,n,n,n,\dots n$?

Comment: Sounds right to me. I am done here, the SE gurus do not like extended disvussions in the comments.

Comment: For the sake of closing this question, I have accepted your answer as it helped me in finding the solution.